# NoraUI - Comparing Value read on GUI

Tags: gherkin, noraui

In my scenario, I have the need to save value taken from the GUI at the one point during the scenario, and comparing them multiple times until the end of the scenario.

Is there a method in `NoraUI` which permit to save value during a step at one point in the scenario, and using them in another steps later in the scenario ?

Comment: What have you tried already? Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how save a backup in context:

```
And I save the value of 'demo.DemoPage-input_text_field'.
```

Here's how to save a backup in the "title" column of the output file:

```
And I save the value of 'demo.DemoPage-big_title' in 'title' column of data output provider.
```

Here is how to use a backup saved in context (If in the context there is a value corresponding to the key "demo.DemoPage-big_title", then it sets this value, otherwise it sets the raw value "demo.DemoPage-big_title"):

```
When I update text 'demo.DemoPage-input_text_field' with 'demo.DemoPage-big_title'.
```

You can find all sample [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/test/resources/steps/hello.feature)

Comment: My case is a little particular, but inspiring myself by what was done with those functionality and using the context function, it's exactly what i needed. and it works fine, thank you !